# Как забиндить suspend-функцию на кнопку?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx-coroutines

Есть какой-то способ это сделать? Я пробовал обёртки и т. п., но не помогает. У меня то не находится `launch`, то `authorization`.

```
class AuthorizationWindow : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val httpclient = HttpClient()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authorization_window)

        binder()
    }

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    private fun binder() {
        val authButton = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.winAuth_inputText_login)

        authButton.setOnClickListener {
            val login = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.winAuth_inputText_login).text.toString()
            val password = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.winAuth_inputText_password).text.toString()
            authorization() // Android Studio "Suspend function 'authorization' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("IntentWithNullActionLaunch")
    suspend fun authorization(login: String, password: String) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Кнопка нажата")
        try {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Начало попытки")
            val response: HttpResponse = httpclient.get("https://example.com/auth/?login=${login}&password=${password}")
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Конец попытки")
        } catch (_: IOException) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Поймал ошибку")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.status).text = "Сервер не ответил"
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Обработал ошибку")
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, MainWindow::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        httpclient.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: launch надо вызвать на чём-то типа lifecycleScope

Comment: Да я уже разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private fun binder() {
        val authButton = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.winAuth_btn_login)

        authButton.setOnClickListener {
            runBlocking {
                authorization(
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.winAuth_inputText_login).text.toString(),
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.winAuth_inputText_password).text.toString()
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

`runBlocking` помог. Данная штука синхронно (блокирующее) запустить корунтину (на сколько я понял).

P. S. А ещё оказалось, что я случайно сделал реплейс подсказок от Android Studio, подсказками от нейросетей (`Tabnine` и ещё одна). А поскольку я до этого в этом проекте ещё не писал ничего похожего, они мне всё сломали :/. Вывод - в начале (когда только создали проект) отключайте расширения-нейросети.

Comment: runBlocking по идее на главном потоке ваш сетевой запрос запустит, что должно бы ошибку кидать соотвтствующую. Даже если этого почему-то не происходит - может ANR случиться на медленном интернете. Вам надо бы в другой поток вынести запрос. Например через `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}` в который завернуть всё что в блоке `try` у вас. Ну и вместо runBlocking используйте скоуп корутин, привязанный к жизненному циклу активити, иначе можно утечек памяти словить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да спасибо. Я как-раз голову ломал, как избавится с зависанием приложения при нажатии.